# Exception on pdf overwite c# (iTextSharp)

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am trying to create a pdf file with iTextSharp . The first time pdf created but when i go deleted programmatically or overwited i get the following exception.

[image: the second time when i run code]

I dont know why document stay open ... Here is my sample code

```
    private void CreatePdf(string first, string last, string value)
    {

        using (MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 100, 100, 100, 100);
            PdfWriter myPDFWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, myMemoryStream);

            document.Open();

            BaseFont MyFont = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf", iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

            var titleFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(MyFont, 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);
            var subTitleFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(MyFont, 22, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            var subTitleFont2 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(MyFont, 16, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            var boldTableFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(MyFont, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
            var endingMessageFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(MyFont, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.ITALIC);
            var bodyFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(MyFont, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

            var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + currentEvent + ".jpg"));
            logo.ScaleToFit(395, 160);

            document.Add(logo);

            Helpers.GetEventInformation(currentEvent);


            Paragraph name = new Paragraph(first, subTitleFont);
            name.Alignment = 1;
            name.SpacingBefore = 20;
            document.Add(name);

            Paragraph surname = new Paragraph(last, subTitleFont);
            surname.Alignment = 1;
            document.Add(surname);


            Paragraph info1 = new Paragraph("Επιβεβαίωση Εγγραφής στο", subTitleFont2);
            info1.Alignment = 1;
            info1.SpacingBefore = 25;
            document.Add(info1);

            Paragraph info2 = new Paragraph(Helpers.confinfo, subTitleFont2);
            info2.Alignment = 1;
            document.Add(info2);

            Paragraph info3 = new Paragraph(Helpers.maildate, titleFont);
            info3.Alignment = 1;
            info3.SpacingBefore = 25;
            document.Add(info3);

            Paragraph info4 = new Paragraph(Helpers.mailtime, subTitleFont2);
            info4.Alignment = 1;
            document.Add(info4);


            document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            var barcodeImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/barcodes/" + value + ".png"));
            barcodeImage.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
            barcodeImage.SpacingBefore = 25;
            document.Add(barcodeImage);

            Paragraph barcodev = new Paragraph(value, endingMessageFont);
            barcodev.SpacingBefore = -5;
            barcodev.Alignment = 1;
            document.Add(barcodev);

            document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            var logo2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/images/footer.jpg"));
            logo2.SpacingBefore = 30;
            logo2.ScaleToFit(395, 130);
            document.Add(logo2);


            document.Close();

            byte[] content = myMemoryStream.ToArray();

            pdfPath = Server.MapPath("~/barcodes/" + value + ".pdf");
            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(pdfPath))
            {
                fs.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't have it open in acrobat or any other pdf-reader by any chance?

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck no i don't

Comment: First of all, iTextSharp as used in the code you present is completely unrelated to the issue as you only use it to create a PDF **in memory**; even the PDF format does not matter per se; the `byte[] content` could just as easily be created in any other manner and contain bytes of any kind. Thus, you should drop the tags [tag:pdf] and [tag:itextsharp] and replace them by tags related to the use of `System.IO.File` and web services.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to close "myPDFWriter"

Comment: I add myPDFWriter.Close(); before document.Open(); but i get the same exception.

Comment: just add it after         document.Close();

Comment: `document.Close()` in particular calls the `Close` method of the underlying `PdfWriter`.

Comment: Furthermore the `PdfWriter` only writes to a `MemoryStream`, not to the file system. Thus, any file system locks obviously are not related to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
My next method sends an email with pdf attached, but the problem was that the pdf file remained open while attaching.

I added this:

```
using (System.Net.Mail.Attachment data = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(bytes)))
            {
                mm.Attachments.Add(data);
                ...
            }
```

and now it is working.